# How to use JColorChooser given Color in other classes?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcomponent, jcolorchooser

I have been learning Java just a few weeks so bear that in mind.. I have managed to solve many issues myself until this one:

What I am trying to achieve is using JComponent in a tabbed view so that in one tab you're able to pick a colour (my println shows it actually gets an sRGB value). Then in another class I should be able to get this value and use it in coloring JPanels. 
Can I just pass the Color object or what is the best way to achieve. What I am trying here is not working too well. Sorry for the messy code - I am a newbie...
Here is the main part of the color chooser:

```
public class Colors extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

    private JColorChooser jcc = null;
    protected JLabel title;
    static Color newColor;

    public Colors() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //Set up the banner at the top of the window
        title = new JLabel();

        //Set up color chooser for setting text color
        jcc = new JColorChooser(title.getForeground());
        jcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
        jcc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                "Choose New Color"));

        AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels=jcc.getChooserPanels();
        for(AbstractColorChooserPanel p:panels) {
            String displayName = p.getDisplayName();
            switch (displayName) {
                case "HSV":
                    jcc.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
                case "HSL":
                    jcc.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
                case "CMYK":
                    jcc.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
                case "RGB":
                    jcc.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
            }
        }
        add(jcc, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }



    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        Color newColor = jcc.getColor();
        title.setForeground(newColor);
        System.out.println("color = " + newColor);
    }

    public static Color getNewCol() {
        System.out.println("this now =" + newColor);
        return newColor;
    }

    public static Component createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color Selector");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new Colors();
        return newContentPane;

    }
}
```

And then I am trying to get hold of the chosen color in the Main.Java class in this way (which is likely wrong). I also note that the value seems to remain always null - probably I am instantiating in a wrong way (value gets lost?)

```
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Click add");
                value++;

                if (value < 21) {


                    JButton jb1 = new JButton();

                    //How to get the COLOR from the JColorChooser class?
                    Color box = Colors.getNewCol();

                    jb1.setBackground(box);
                    jb1.setOpaque(true);

                    //FOR TEST ONLY jb1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
                    panel.add(jb1);
                    panel.setVisible(true);

                    //window.add(paneeli);

                    window.pack();

                    d = new Dimension(700, 500);
                    window.setSize(d);
```

Probably the answer is too obvious but I just can't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get take your static newColor variable and make it non-static. In my ChangeListener I'd fire the JPanel's innate PropertyChangeSupport so that listeners can be notified. The key is to use an observer design pattern -- For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestColors extends JPanel {
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private Colors colors = new Colors();
    private JPanel colorDisplayPanel = new JPanel();

    public TestColors() {
        tabbedPane.add("Colors", colors);
        tabbedPane.add("Color Display", colorDisplayPanel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tabbedPane);

        // add a PropertyChangeListener to our Colors isntance.
        colors.addPropertyChangeListener(Colors.NEW_COLOR,
                new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        Color color = (Color) evt.getNewValue();
                        colorDisplayPanel.setBackground(color);
                    }
                });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestColors");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestColors());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Colors extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {
    public static final String NEW_COLOR = "new color";
    private JColorChooser jcc = null;
    protected JLabel title;
    private Color newColor = null;

    public Colors() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        // Set up the banner at the top of the window
        title = new JLabel("This is my Banner!", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        // Set up color chooser for setting text color
        jcc = new JColorChooser(title.getForeground());
        jcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
        jcc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose New Color"));

        add(jcc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(title, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // Color newColor = jcc.getColor();
        Color oldValue = newColor;
        newColor = jcc.getColor();

        // fire a notification to the Colors JPanel's property change support
        // object. Any listeners will be notified of the color change
        firePropertyChange(NEW_COLOR, oldValue, newColor);
        title.setForeground(newColor);
    }

    public Color getNewCol() {
        System.out.println("this now =" + newColor);
        return newColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: That was a great hint! I wasn't actually even aware of the PropertyChangeListener for JPanel in .beans libraries. I have adopted your proposed changes to Colors.java almost as is and adopted also most parts in the Main.java. Your code proved that the color from JColorChooser can be adopted and used as background color for the frontPg. However, I am still struggling with how to use that (selected) Color in other method for new JButton background (user should select the color of new buttons, and "add" should show new btn with new clr".

Comment: I am still stuck with not being able to pass the instances of Color around since PropertyChangeListener etc. are quite strictly defined (and allow no return value). Should I expand them with my own methods to pass Color to other classes or what is the best approach?

Comment: @JackGarfield: property change listeners **do** have an effective return value -- the `getNewValue()` returned from the PropertyChangeEvent. But regardless, another solution is to call a getter method from the listened-to class whenever the listener notifies listeners of an event. I'm sure that you can figure the specifics out. If not, ask a new question and post your [mcve].

Comment: thanks for the hints, I am studying that property listener now more carefully... I posted the full code also here, although I think it mostly is around the same topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975232/passing-color-object-between-two-views-to-be-used-in-jbutton-background

Comment: One more request - can someone validate that (now as it finally works), this is the right kind of call (or not just some lucky accident:-)                       col = colors.getNewCol();